# LINQ to SQL Repository pattern auto increment problem

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-2, repository-pattern

I have weird problem and I'm trying to figure out whether it is my code or something has been messed up with database. I have a table WebClienteLogin which has an attribute Id (primary key, auto increment). I'm inserting new record when user registers on the website.

Yesterday morning the value Id of the last registered user reached around 9000 and in the afternoon it started to jump in a funny way, so the next user had Id 1200, 25000 ..... and it reached 290000. However, today it continues as normal (incrementing by 1). From the statistics I see it happening when there is a big amount of users registering at the same time.

Technologies used: SQL Server 2008 R2,ASP.NET MVC2, .NET 3.5

I'm using Repository pattern with LINQ. Here is my implementation of one of my repositories.

```
public SQLWebClientLoginRepository(string connectionString)
{
                dataContext = new DataContext(connectionString);
                tabla = dataContext.GetTable<WebClientLogin>(); 
}


public bool Save(WebClientLogin user)
            {
                bool success = true;            

                try
                {
                    if (user.Id == 0)
                    {
                        tabla.InsertOnSubmit(user);
                    }
                    else if (tabla.GetOriginalEntityState(user) == null)
                    {
                        tabla.Attach(user);
                        tabla.Context.Refresh(RefreshMode.KeepCurrentValues, user);
                    }
                    tabla.Context.SubmitChanges();  
                }
                catch
                {
                    ......
                }

                return success;
     }
```

Also the user has other object attached so it does INSERT into two tables and LINQ wraps it into transaction.

```
  var user = new WebClientLogin();
  // assigning other properties
  user.WebClient = new WebClient { // setting propeties }

  webClientLoginRepository.Save(user)
```

In log I get exception:

An attempt was made to remove a 
relationship between a WebClientLogin and a WebCLient 
However, one of the relationship's foreign keys 
(WebClient.WebCLientLogin_id) cannot be set to null." exception

I have no idea why is it doing that! Anyone experienced anything similar?

Answer (score 0):

Starting database state:

```
WebClientLogin
ID = 900

WebClient
ID = 1, WebClientLogin_Id = 900
```

In memory before modifications:

```
WebClientLogin
ID = 900

WebClient
ID = 1, WebClientLogin_Id = 900, WebClientLogin = that instance with 900
```

Examine the WebClient property of WebClientLogin.  In memory at the time of SubmitChanges:

```
WebClientLogin
ID = 900

WebClient (original instance)
ID = 1, WebClientLogin_Id = 900, WebClientLogin = null

WebClient  (new instance!)
ID = 0, WebClientLogin_Id = 900, WebClientLogin = that instance with 900
```

Attempted changes in the database:

```
WebClientLogin (no change)
ID = 900

WebClient (new row, inserted)
ID = 2, WebClientLogin_Id = 900

WebClient (original row, updated)
ID = 1, WebClientLogin_Id = 900 -> null  (error, rollback transaction)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. All seems to be correct and WebClientLogin property is assigned correctly. It is quite difficult case as it only happens when users are "bombarding" registration form so I actually can't debug it. I would have to write to log property values of every user that is registering.

Comment: In that case I would in fact log everything. You should also build a stress test for your app and run that against your local debug code to simulate the registration bombardment and reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I modified slightly repository but and seems that it fixed that problem but now I've got another.

```
public bool Save(WebClientLogin login, WebClient client)
        {
            var created = false;

            using (var transaction = new TransactionScope())
            {
                try
                {
     // insert WebClientLogin first
                    tablalogin.InsertOnSubmit(login);
                    dataContext.SubmitChanges();

     // insert WebClient second
                    client.WebClientLogin_id = login.Id;
                    tablacliente.InsertOnSubmit(client);

                    dataContext.SubmitChanges();
                    created = true;
                    transaction.Complete();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //
                }
            }
            return created;
        }
```

When there is a high volume of users I only WebClientLogin is inserted but no WebClient
and I get this exception:

```
Internal .Net Framework Data Provider error 60
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to do direct ID management like that.  Check out the WebClientLogin property of a WebClient and see how the autogenerated property manages the ids.  Should be able to make one call to SubmitChanges.

Comment: I am aware of that. That is what I was doing before as SubmitChanges() wraps the whole thing into transaction but when I had it done that way I got those funny jumps of Id ONLY if there was a huge amount of users registering at the same time. Otherwise is fine. Code above seemed to fix the thing. However, sometimes fails to do INSERT to both tables using TransactionScope. So I end up with some users being entered into only 1 table. I'm going crazy with this stuff!

Answer (score 0):

Well....the whole application was giving loads of other weird exceptions. So we visited our host and we had discovered what caused it. The host configured 3 dedicated web servers and 1 database server. They configured load balancer and dfs for web servers. They had shut down 2 out of 3 servers and performed stress test. Since then there was no errors/exceptions or faulty transactions. Seems like a server issue.